# Empty database in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to empty an entire database by connecting to it with PHP and giving a command?

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way to do it, if you have the privileges, is:

```
DROP DATABASE dbName;
CREATE DATABASE dbName;
USE DATABASE dbName;
```

The alternative is to query the `information_schema` database for triggers, stored routines (procedures and functions), tables, views and possibly something else, and drop them individually.

Even after this, your database might still not be in the same state as a newly created one, since it might have a custom default character set and collation set. Use `ALTER DATABASE` to change that.

As features keep getting added (events...) you'll have more and more work this way. So really, the only way to completely empty the database is to drop it and re-create it.

Comment: you will lose the table's structure

Comment: Well the topic starter didn't say anything except he wants an empty database with the same name, so it perfectly answered the question.

It has no sense to make possibly wrong assumptions, that's why this answer got +1 from me.

Comment: If the user does not have `CREATE DATABASE`  privilege, they will be stuck.

Comment: To use the database just `USE dbName;` without the `DATABASE` keyword.

Answer (score 7):

You can get table names with

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your db'
```

And make the truncate,

even, you can make

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + table_name + ';' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your db'
```

And then iterate the resultset executing the string query for each record.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of all tables in a database (`$databaseName`), loop through them all, and apply `TRUNCATE TABLE` to each.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW TABLES IN `$databaseName`"); 
while ($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tableName = $table[0];
    mysqli_query($link, "TRUNCATE TABLE `$databaseName`.`$tableName`");

    if (mysqli_errno($link)) echo mysqli_errno($link) . ' ' . mysqli_error($link);
    else echo "$tableName was cleared<br>";
}
```

This clears the contents of all the tables in a database, keeping the structure.

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Basically, you need to get a list of all Tables in the Database, then iterate over that list and issue a `TRUNCATE TABLE $tablename` for each entry.

This looks like a decent enough implementation: [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database](http://david-burger.blogspot.com/2008/02/truncate-all-tables-in-mysql-database.html)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
mysql -u < DB-USER > -p<DB-PASS> --silent --skip-column-names -e "SHOW TABLES" <DB-NAME> | xargs -L1 -I% echo 'DROP TABLE `%`;' | mysql -u < DB-USER > -p< DB-PASS > -v < DB-NAME >
```

Comment: This does not work when they are foreign key constraints

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE '".$db."'";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $tables = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE `".$table['TABLE_NAME']."`";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: please add description with your solution for better understanding

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21444348)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can connect the database and Truncate the table by assigning as a variable.

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$variableName = $conn->query($que);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

$result = $conn->query('TRUNCATE TABLE yourtablename;');

```
if ($result) {

    echo "Request ID table has been truncated";  

   }

   else echo "Something went wrong: " . mysqli_error();
```