# Clear data in MySQL table with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I clear all the entries from just one table in MySQL with PHP?

Comment: Simple and easy solution: https://queception.com/question.php?question=116

Answer (score 48):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

or

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

The first one is usually the better choice, as DELETE FROM is slow on InnoDB.

Actually, wasn't this already answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725879/empty-database-in-mysql-and-php)?

Comment: And from a requirement perspective, truncate will reset the indicies whereas delete won't.

Comment: Simple and easy solution: https://queception.com/question.php?question=116

Answer (score 16):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table;
```

is the SQL command. In PHP, you'd use:

```
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE table;');
```

Comment: mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE table');

Answer (score 15):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table`
```

unless you need to preserve the current value of the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence, in which case you'd probably prefer

```
DELETE FROM `table`
```

though if the time of the operation matters, saving the AUTO_INCREMENT value, truncating the table, and then restoring the value using

```
ALTER TABLE `table` AUTO_INCREMENT = value
```

will happen a lot faster.

Answer (score 10):

MySQLI example where $con is the database connection variable and table name is: mytable.

```
mysqli_query($con,'TRUNCATE TABLE mytable');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mytable
```

Be careful with it though.

Answer (score 3):

TRUNCATE will blank your table and reset primary key 
DELETE  will also make your table blank but it will not reset primary key.

we can use for truncate

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

we can use for delete

```
DELETE FROM tablename
```

we can also give conditions as below

DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id='xyz'

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe the MySQL optimizer carries out a TRUNCATE when you DELETE all rows.