# how to delete all rows of a table with name query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need a name query annotation to delete all rows of a table with hibernate
how to do it

Comment: with simple sql `Delete from table where true;`

Comment: What??? To delete all rows in a table in MySQL, `DELETE FROM t WHERE true`

Comment: Duplicates: [Clear data in MySQL table with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725982/clear-data-in-mysql-table-with-php) and [Delete mysql table rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976408/delete-mysql-table-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delete all rows

```
delete from table where condition
```

to delete the entire table from the database

```
 drop table from db
```